# Can xamarin apps be built for Windows, MacOS with same source code?

Tags: xamarin, platform

Given an app written in C# for Xamarin, can it be built to run on all the supported platforms with minimal changes, including Android, iOS, MacOS, Windows?

I realize that Xamarin claims 90% of the code is shareable across platforms (and 10% needs to be customized), and I'm referring to that "90%".

*What I don't understand is whether that 90% is shareable across the different Xamarin tools,e.g. Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Mac or if those are substantially different tools with different APIs, etc.*

For example, I see that with Xamarin.Forms I can build for iOS, Android, and Windows. But not MacOS. So, on a Mac, can I install Xamarin.Mac and then build the same app for MacOS ?

Comment: This question is more or less opinion based. So in some way you can build for macOS, but it is in beta, has a good amount of bugs (this may be fixed in the future) and looks awful (unlikely to be fixed anytime soon). So for some things it may be OK, for some not, there isn't a universal answer it is opinion based...

Comment: Not meant to be subjective. See my question in the 3rd para, now in italics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms is the framework that allows you to create cross-platform apps between Android, iOS and UWP.  In my experience, a lot of the features of Xamarin.Forms do not transfer over to Xamarin.Android.  In fact, a big chunk of the way things are done for UI Xamarin.Forms will not transfer over to the Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.  Most of the times when I find a solution that works in Xamarin.Forms and I try to do the same thing in Xamarin.Android I end up just figuring out the problem myself in Xamarin.Android from scratch.

When they say that 90% is shared, they mean that within Xamarin.Forms... 90% of the work on your models and code behind can be shared between the projects (within that Xamarin.Forms solution) and 10% will have to be custom tailored for each platform (UWP, Android, iOS)

EDIT: Just for clarification in the future, you need an iOS device or an iOS virtual machine to compile the code on iOS

> To build Xamarin.iOS apps with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows, you will
> need:
>
> ```
> A Windows machine with Visual Studio 2019 installed.
> ```
>
> This can be a physical or a virtual machine.
> Windows system requirements
>
> ```
> A network-accessible Mac set up with Apple's build tools and Xamarin.iOS.
> ```
>
> Visual Studio 2019 accesses this machine over a network
> connection to use Apple's build tools, which are required for
> compiling native iOS applications.
> Mac system requirements

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/?pivots=windows

Comment: So, do the different Xamarin tools, e.g. .Forms, .Mac, allow you to build the same source code to produce an app on different platforms. Or are they altogether separate environments with different APIs?

Comment: @PeriHartman some of the code can be reused across platforms.  Most of your model and anything that is purely .NET will be fully transferable across all Xamarin platforms.  The largest differences come when you start to build out the UI.  Xamarin.Forms with an Android project is not the same as a purely Xamarin.Android project and same with Xamarin.iOS ,, for example, Xamarin.Forms supports data binding to the UI without any third party libraries whereas I don't believe you can do that with Xamarin.Android so that's a major example of a difference that wouldn't translate.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I guess for me to fully understand, I need to build something. But this gives me the encouragement to try that step.

Comment: Hey just as a quick clarification I think you actually can do data binding in Xamarin.Android without third party libraries.  There is a huge difference though.  The Xamarin.Forms databinding is a lot easier to do and more native to that type of project; it's almost identical to data binding in WPF and a LOT smoother.

Comment: Yes to people reading this after the fact.. I smell some preconceived notions here. To clarify. Yes, as of this date, you can build an app that will run on Windows, Web, OSX, Linux, WPF, Android, and OSX right out of the box. You have only one "Main" project with all your logic that is compiled for you in all the platforms. You can use XAML to design your layouts just like WPF, and this layout will work on all devices. Some tweaks will be needed but you solve these with platform specific XAML tags. Other advanced features of the phone you may need to mess around in the respective libraries

Comment: @PeriHartman just as an update I found out that not everything .NET is fully transferable to all platforms.  Some of the libraries don't translate over.  They will let you compile the app but get runtime errors.  I believe one example of this is the Image class in .NET to Xamarin.Android compile. I had yet to encounter that when this was posted, but since I've seen it happen more than once.  I still love xamarin though, overall.. mostly just for the C#

Answer (score 3):

You can add a MacOS target for your `Xamarin.Forms`-based UI, of course, this is done via Visual Studio for Mac:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/mac

There are items within Forms that are not feature complete on MacOS and thus it is still in a "Preview" release and those are listed on the "Platform Support macOS Status" wiki:

- https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/wiki/Platform-Support-macOS-Status

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use .Net code and Xamarin.Forms it is 100% portable/sharable across every single project. Xamarin.Forms are currently in beta for macOS and Windows WPF (but for UWP it is not beta), and for macOS particularly they don't have the true native look.

Xamarin does support using the native interfaces and native APIs and whenever you do that, it is not portable.

So there is nothing like 90% sharable, it may be some estimate for some cases. It can be 100% sharable or it can be only 10% sharable depending on your project and how much you stick to the sharable APIs.

Comment: Ok, so if I write an app for Xamarin.Forms, can I build it with one of the othe Xamarin tools, e.g. Xamarin.Android? (I understand the "90%" - of course if I use native APIs that code won't be portable.)